# Javascript scoped access performance - 25 times slower?

Tags: javascript, performance, scope

I am a little bewildered by the extraordinary difference in the apparent speed of execution when assigning to variables declared in a function, and assigning to variables within the upper scope.

I have wrote a little measure function which I keep on the global scope for these kind of things, here's some results:

**Chrome (console)**

```
measure("assignment to var in current scope", function(){
  var i = 1;
  (function(){})(i)
})
15:52:49 |INFO| Measure 'assignment to var in current scope' performed 76236944 operations per second
iterations: 10000000    duration: 141   totalcalllag: 9.83
```

... and in the upper scope

```
var i = 0;
measure("assignment to var in upper scope", function(){
  i = 1;
  (function(){})(i)
})
15:53:22 |INFO| Measure 'assignment to var in upper scope' performed 2935124 operations per second
iterations: 10000000    duration: 3417  totalcalllag: 9.99
```

That is **76 million** ops/sec for assignment in scope compared with **3million** ops/sec for assignment in upper scope for a ratio of ~ **1:25**!

---

**IE11 (console)**

```
measure("assignment to var in current scope", function(){
  var i = 1;
  (function(){})(i)
})
15:54:14|INFO| Measure 'assignment to var in current scope' performed 46038396 operations per second
iterations: 10000000    duration: 247   totalcalllag: 29.790000000000002

var i = 0;
measure("assignment to var in upper scope", function(){
  i = 1;
  (function(){})(i)})
8669267
15:54:49 |INFO| Measure 'assignment to var in upper scope' performed 8669267 operations per second
iterations: 10000000    duration: 1183  totalcalllag: 29.5
```

Here we see **46 million** as opposed to **8.5 million** ops per second.

---

**The measure function**

```
var measure = function (desc, f) {

    // measure the calling code first
    var start, stop, callLag, nothing = function () {
    };
    var iterations = 0;
    var COUNT = 1000;
    var duration = 0;
    while (duration < 10) {
        COUNT *= 1000;
        start = (new Date()).getTime();
        while (iterations != COUNT) {
            ++iterations;
            nothing();
        }
        stop = (new Date()).getTime();
        duration = stop - start;
    }
    callLag = duration / COUNT;

    // measure for total time between 0.1 & 10 seconds
    iterations = 0;
    COUNT = 1000;
    duration = 0;
    while (duration < 100) {
        COUNT *= 100;
        start = (new Date()).getTime();
        while (iterations != COUNT) {
            ++iterations;
            f();
        }
        stop = (new Date()).getTime();
        duration = stop - start;
    }

    // calculate operations per second
    var opsPerSec = Math.floor(1000 * (iterations / (duration - (callLag * iterations))));

    Log.info("Measure '" + desc + "' performed " + opsPerSec.toString() + " operations per second\n" +
        "\titerations: " + iterations + "\tduration: " + duration + "\ttotalcalllag: " + callLag*iterations);

    return opsPerSec;
};
```

---

**Questions**

I am going to be doing some heavy number crunching with JavaScript soon. Is this behaviour consistent across all browsers? Should I be implementing functions with this in mind? Should I pass parameters to functions internally to avoid accessing them within an upper scope?

... or have I just missed something?

Comment: This is probably not be the answer you are looking for but JavaScript is not the best choice for heavy number crunching. If other alternatives are available you would be better off using them. (Sometimes you have no choice but to use JavaScript, but it depends whether this is one of those times).

Comment: It is mostly for online character recognition - in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In theory it shouldn't make any difference in JavaScript. Variable declaration is very important when it comes to JavaScript since language only has a `function scope` (as oppose to block scope). I always follow the advice given by JavaScript guru Douglas Crockford (Author of Javascript: The Good Parts).

`JavaScript does not have block scope, so defining variables in blocks can confuse programmers who are experienced with other C family languages. Define all variables at the top of the function.`

Please read more details at: [Variable Declarations](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#variable%20declarations)

I would also recommend using Crockford's [JSLint: The JavaScript Code Quality Tool](http://www.jslint.com/) He also puts warning: `JSLint will hurt your feelings`

Comment: I did try adopting this advice, but found my code much more readable/maintainable, in javascript at least, if I just declare the variables closest to where they are used. It doesn't affect performance.

There would be a performance hit for looking up the scope for a variable, but it shouldn't be this gargantuan! Maybe all current scope variables are held in the CPU cache? I don't know.

Comment: I have always wondered about that too. CPU cache would be the fastest way to access them making it less expensive to look up variables in other scopes. Also please take a look at OReilly's "Writing Efficient JavaScript: Chapter 7" here: http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html

Comment: + 1 for the link. Nicholas sure does know his stuff. I first learnt JavaScript (properly) from his books :)